# React Native Text component not render anything if text string is large

Tags: react-native, react-native-text

React Native Text component not render anything if text string is large.
Anyone has seen the same issue or has any solution? 
If I continue increase the string text size, at some point, the {someString} will not render anything.

Here is small demo project to show the problem:
https://github.com/peid2l/ReactNativeTextIssue

### The amount of text needed to make Text component stop working is not that super large, 17 time of the following amount of text will do.

"

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no deserunt argumentum has, brute mnesarchum id mei. Sapientem sadipscing at qui. Sea ei noster iudicabit, vis exerci intellegat ei. Ei dolore omittantur usu. Viderer repudiandae ad his, vocibus offendit aliquando vis in.

Mel ne tractatos petentium, nullam perpetua repudiandae nec te, idque postulant ius te. Unum verterem id per, ius et mucius erroribus suscipiantur. Cum ex dictas tritani pericula, ei prompta instructior eum. Omnium efficiendi ei mei. Cum te ipsum quodsi detracto, cum fastidii complectitur te.

"

Comment: Did you solve this? I am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Using flex:1 as a style should solve your problem.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}><Text>lorem ipsum</Text></View>
```